# Reference to a type of implicit function theorem.

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, geometric-measure-theory, implicit-function-theorem

I wonder if the propositions below are well known results in mathematical analysis literature. Any reference containing their demonstration?

> **Proposition.** Let $X$ and $Y$ complete and separable metric spaces. If $f:X\times K\to \mathbb{R}$ a bounded upper semicontinuous function and   $K\subset Y$ compact. Then
>
> - $X\ni x\longmapsto \max_{y\in K}f(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}$ is upper semicontinuous on $X$ and,
> - there exists a mensurable $\varphi:X\to K$ for which 
>     $$
>    f(x,\varphi(x))=\max_{y\in K} f(x,y).
>    $$

This seems to be a kind of implicit function theorem. I did not find anything like that in the book of Steven G Krantz & Harold R. Parks (  [link 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/146145980X), [link 2](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461200598)). I also tried to follow the referêcias I could find in the excellent [post of Tao](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75049/does-the-inverse-function-theorem-hold-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps). But without success.